# How to change the paths to shared libraries (.so files) for a single terminal instance

Tags: libraries, dependencies, shared-library, linker

I want to remove some of the paths the linker uses to find .so libraries for testing purposes.

I have found a way to add library paths:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/library"
```

Are there a variable similar to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` that I can use to remove library paths such as `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/lib` that are not in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but picked up by the linker? I.e. how can I ignore paths that are given in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ ?

The reason for this is that I am busy creating a program that, for a given executable, it recursively finds library dependencies. I want to see if I can make a program more portable by finding all its dependencies, copying those dependencies into a local directory, and make a local-run bash script to setup LD_LIBRARY_PATH and then run the executable. I want to test if this local-run-executable works after previously important library search paths are removed.

Comment: If you want to test with another version of so while not messing with the binary. [LD_PRELOAD trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/426260/4123703) might help. I know it's a bit off topic, but some people might need it while their search engine leads to here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would be interested in *removing* library paths if a given *shared* library has embedded paths via the *rpath* feature.  Those are added at the time the library is created by the linker.

You can remove (or alter) those paths using [`chrpath`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chrpath), e.g.,

```
chrpath -d mylibraryfile.so
```

Removing pathnames from the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable also is a possible area of interest; you can do that by string substitution and re-exporting the variable.  However, the question does not seem to be concerned with that.  There is no variable which acts to cancel out `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

For *seeing* library dependencies, the mention of `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` makes it sound as if the platform is only Linux.  You can use `ldd` to list dependencies.  Aside from OSX, all of the BSDs also support `ldd`.  Here is one of the scripts which I use for this purpose:

```
#!/bin/sh
# $Id: ldd-path,v 1.1 2007/07/09 19:30:28 tom Exp $
# Edit the output of ldd for the given parameters, yielding only the
# absolute pathnames.
ldd $* | sed \
        -e 's/([^)]*)//g' \
        -e 's/^.*=>//' \
        -e 's/[         ][      ]*//g' \
        -e '/^$/d'
```

But (addressing a comment), there is no portable mechanism for telling the loader to *ignore* an existing path.  The GNU ld documentation gives a summary of what is sought, and the order in the description of the [`-rpath`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options) option.  These items conclude the list:

> - The default directories, normally `/lib` and `/usr/lib`.
> - For a native linker on an ELF system, if the file `/etc/ld.so.conf` exists, the list of directories found in that file.

Further reading

- [Can I change 'rpath' in an already compiled binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769141/can-i-change-rpath-in-an-already-compiled-binary)
- [RPATH, RUNPATH, and dynamic linking](http://blog.tremily.us/posts/rpath/)

Comment: If I am correctly reading this answer, then you have given me a tool to make my portable-isation robust against embedded paths in the library (thanks, willl have a look!). Or am I missing something? Will follow your links.

Comment: yes - I've used this tool to remove paths (incorrectly) added by developers which interfere with building packages.

Comment: I have edited my question to be more specific (how can I ignore paths that are given in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/). Although very useful (thanks), this does not quite answers my question.

Comment: Short: you can't do that portably.  You can only add paths to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which are checked *before* the linker's defaults.