# How to change the path of shared libraries shown by ldd?

Tags: libraries, dynamic-linking, postgresql, shared-library

I am trying to make the postgis extension work on my system and it always spits out "$libdir/postgis2.2" no such file or directory error. For my curiosity I executed "ldd postgis-2.2.so" and it spits out the following result :

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff3bc8000)
    /usr/lib64/libjemalloc.so.1 (0x00002b3fe5ff4000)
    libgeos_c.so.1 => not found
    libproj.so.9 => not found
    libjson-c.so.2 => not found
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00002b3fe6237000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b3fe659e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b3fe689c000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b3fe6c41000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00002b3fe5b2e000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b3fe6e5d000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00002b3fe7061000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00002b3fe7277000)
```

And for a bunch of dependencies I see the path to their so is not present. This I guess is happening because I am not building postgis but just copying the required so's and libs to make it work manually. But I do know the path to those so files that are required by postgis. What should I do such that I can change the "not found" in dependencies to the required path by postgis?

Comment: Can you edit your answer to post the output from `ldconfig -v`?

Comment: Are those libraries already installed?  Did you follow the installation instructions provided by `postgis`?

Comment: I stored the so files manually including the libs and bins.

Comment: It's a hack I want urgent in my project so trying to make it work

Comment: Well make sure the libraries that it doesn't find are in a directory present in your `/etc/ld.so.conf`.

Answer (score 11):

This has been covered in part in many tutorials, but I feel many of the solutions are missing a basic example.

- For Linux, [`patchelf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20333550/3196753) can accomplish this on Linux.
- For MacOS, there's a tool called [`install_name_tool`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53737831/3196753).

Assuming you're using for Linux:

> **Note:** `patchelf` is not installed by default on many systems.  You can install it using `apt install patchelf`, `dnf install patchelf`, `pacman install patchelf` or whatever your package manager provides.

```bsh
patchelf --print-needed mysharedobject.so

# outputs:
../libsomething1.so
libsomething2.so.1
```

Replace the path to a required library:

```bsh
patchelf --replace-needed ../libsomething1.so /foo/bar/libsomething1.so mysharedobject.so
```

Test the new path:

```bsh
patchelf --print-needed mysharedobject.so

# outputs:
/foo/bar/libsomething1.so 
libsomething2.so.1
```

**Note:** Many tutorials recommend another tool called [`chrpath`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272279/how-to-change-the-paths-to-shared-libraries-so-files-for-a-single-terminal-in) which can help `.so` files that have a `rpath` attribute set but it does not appear to work with libraries missing rpath nor have the ability to change the absolute link location.

Comment: `patchelf --replace-needed` does the job , however the `rpath` printed by `ldd` remains same as original dependency path

Comment: I believe you will want to use [`chrpath`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272279/how-to-change-the-paths-to-shared-libraries-so-files-for-a-single-terminal-in) for that.

Answer (score 10):

`ld.so`, the dynamic linker, will use the `PATH`-like environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when it looks for shared libraries to link at execution time.

You may set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to a `:`-delimited list of directories where the linker should look for libraries, for example:

```
$ env LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$HOME/local/lib:/opt/other/lib" ./myprog
```

See the `ld.so` manual on your system for more information.