# Is there an rpath for dynamic linked libraries?

Tags: libraries, dynamic-linking, shared-library

So, the project I am working on uses a non-system directory to keep some DLLs that the code uses.  I don't want to put them in system directories, so the executables have an rpath set to find the DLLs.  However, as more and more libraries are added, there are now DLLs that depend on other DLLs in that directory.

Those libraries cannot find the DLLs that they depend on, since they are not located in a directory that the linker is looking for, e.g. a system directory.

Is there a way to get the DLLs to search this specific non-system directory?  Such as an rpath?  And how is that done with a library?  The build system being used for the project is CMake, if that assists in the answer.

This answer does not work, since there is no rPath tag in the library: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/272286/4193

I have considered using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and that works, but it is annoying to type and not all that great to get other people to use the app. If there is a way to add the `rPath` tag to the library, that would be the best option.

Pointers to previous relevant questions and answers appreciated.

Comment: Would setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the runtime work for you? It would also simplify the build system.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, that works, but it is annoying to type and not all that great to get other people to use the app.  If there is a way to add the rPath tag to the library, that would be the best option.

Comment: You can create a shell wrapper that would set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, call the app via `exec` and pass all arguments to the app itself via `$@`. You can putt a wrapper in path, call it `app` for example and call the real app `app-bin`.

Comment: And, why don't you want to put the shared objects in `/usr/lib` or `/usr/lib64` in the first place?

Comment: And why do you think that shared objects cannot have `-Wl,-rpath` set? Because they can.

Comment: See a little example I put up here https://gist.github.com/ardrabczyk/6aeb8545c9b754d6b15be390af4bdff0

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, that is the answer.  Please add an answer to collect your easy 100 points. :)  There was some fiddling to get $ORIGIN working, but it all works now.  Specifically, if the libraries are in the same directory (as they would be in my project), then just $ORIGIN is sufficient (actually had to use \$$ORIGIN in the Makefile, though).

Comment: Oh yeah, lib_two.c has to call foo() from lib_one.c to actually qualify.  I tested with that and it worked (with both libraries in the same directory and using $ORIGIN as described).

Comment: @casualunixer: what is `$ORIGIN` for you?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, $ORIGIN is a special path that the tells the library to only search in the directory it was loaded from.  In your example. $ORIIGN/lib would only search for the libtwo from where libone was loaded.  It limits scooping in random other libraries from whom knows where.  Handy for this purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there an rpath for dynamic linked libraries?

Yes, there is.  You can use `-Wl,-rpath` with ELF shared objects just
like with ELF executables. Clone a little example I put up
[here](https://gist.github.com/ardrabczyk/6aeb8545c9b754d6b15be390af4bdff0):

```
git clone https://gist.github.com/ardrabczyk/6aeb8545c9b754d6b15be390af4bdff0
```

Run `make` to compile. Check what libraries are needed by the `main`
ELF executable:

```
$ readelf -d ./main

Dynamic section at offset 0xe30 contains 22 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libtwo.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [.]
(...)
```

And check what libraries are needed by `libtwo.so`:

```
$ readelf -d ./libtwo.so

Dynamic section at offset 0xe38 contains 22 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libone.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000f (RPATH)              Library rpath: [libs]
 (...)
```

As you can see both `main` and `libtwo.so` need some shared objects
and both have rpath set. You don't need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to run
./main:

```
$ ./main
I'm in bar()
```

main will always look for its libtwo.so dependency in `.` that is a
current directory and libtwo.so in turn will always look for its
libone.so dependency in `libs` directory. If `libs` is missing ./main
will not start:

```
$ mv libs libs.bak
$ ./main
./main: error while loading shared libraries: libone.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Restore it:

```
$ mv libs.bak libs
$ ./main
I'm in bar()
```

Comment: I didnt knpw rpath was a thing in programming. I like the explainations. Under Windows programs always look into their own directory. Now i know, how Linux does handle this. Good answer!

Comment: I think you have demonstrated that main depends on libone.so due to the link line, rather than that libtwo depends on libone. This is easy to fix by making lib_two.c call foo().  Then moving aside libone.so should cause libtwo.so to fail when main is run. 
Then the answer will be complete.

Comment: @casualunixer: sorry, I don't get your point.  main doesn't depend on
`libone.so`, it depends on `libtwo.so` which in turn depends on
`libone.so.`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk, I missed that you included libone.so in the link line for libtwo.  Everything is fine.

Comment: If `./main` had `libs` in its rpath, but `libtwo.so` didn't, would `libone.so` still be found when executing `./main`? My tests seem to indicate this is the case. So I'm wondering if when loading `libtwo.so`, the dynamic loader still consults the rpath in `./main`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't wanna consider it as part of the system, use it as what it is; an user application!

If you add `~/.local/lib/` to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, you can put everything there. Just create a partial FHS structure under `~/.local/` like *bin*, *etc*, *lib* and *share*. That way you don't need to call the program with a preceding environmemt variable. All other systems would just need to append this directory their library path environment variable. Very tidy and unixish.

If you reject this solution as well, there is only one possibility left. Either you use a fixed path, which is expected on every system or an environment variable, which contains a path and is also expected.

Comment: OP already said they don't want that solution. Read comments before answering.

Comment: @Arkadiusz updates shouldn't be in comments; they should be in the question

Comment: @roaima: ok, I've updated the question